# Firebase error:Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: true"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase error:Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: true"

```
  **my update function**
     editproduct(product){
            this.modal='edit'
            this.product=product
            this.activeitem=product.id
            $("#product").modal('show')
            },
        upproduct(){
         this.$firestore.products.doc(this.product.id).update(this.product)
          $('#product').modal('hide')
          },
```

Comment: What exactly is the value you're passing to `doc()`? The error is telling you the problem with it.

Comment: it would seem that `this.product.id` has an invalid/empty value

Comment: passing my product id

Comment: Vue.use(VueFirestore, {
    key: 'id',         // the name of the property. Default is '.key'.
    enumerable: true  //  whether it is enumerable or not. Default is true.
})